# How to remove emoji insertions in Entries and Textviews in GTK?

Tags: user-interface, gtk

When we work with Entries and Textviews in GTK, it's possible for the user to add emojis in the text content, by just clicking with the mouse right button on the widget, then clicking on "Insert Emoji". My question is: how to remove emoji insertions in Entries and Textviews in GTK? I am using Gtk 3 + C programming in a GNOME desktop, but other languages might have similar solution.

See an image about the issue:

[image]

Comment: Do you mean: how to remove the "Insert Emoji" item from the menu?

Comment: Yes, I want to remove the "Insert Emoji" option, but removing the possibility to insert them through clipboard or other means is also desirable. My entries and textviews have to not have any emoji.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the option with `gtk_text_view_set_input_hints (view, GTK_INPUT_HINT_NO_EMOJI)` for `GtkTextView` and  `gtk_entry_set_input_hints (entry, GTK_INPUT_HINT_NO_EMOJI)` for `GtkEntry`

If you don't want to modify existing input hints, you can do `gtk_entry_set_input_hints (entry, gtk_entry_get_input_hints (entry) | GTK_INPUT_HINT_NO_EMOJI)`

in GTK4, `gtk_text_set_input_hints()` can also be used where it's applicable